# How to get response along with error when calling signInWithEmailAndPassword in firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I am using signInWithEmailAndPassword like this

```
 firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(uEmail, currentPassword)
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert("Invalid current password.");
        });
```

But I would like to return the response as well as catch the error. The reason for this is because I am using this to check a users current password before letting them change to a new password. So I need to be able to see if either the error, or a successful sign in was returned so I can then either let the password be changed or display the error message. Is there a way to do this? Thanks so much =]

Comment: What do you mean by "return the response as well as catch the error"?  What exactly do you want to return, and where is that data going?  It's not clear from the code you have here.

Comment: I need a way to see if the sign in was successful as well as if there was an error. There shouldnt need to be more code provided, its a real basic question and everything needed to come up with an answer is included.

Comment: I am using this in a change password form. First I am checking their current password via the code above, then if it is correct, then I want to run another piece of code that changes the password. Right now I can only see if there was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .then before .catch like below.

```
 firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(uEmail, currentPassword)
        .then(function (data) {
          // success sign in, do stuff
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert("Invalid current password.");
        });
```

Comment: Thanks friend =] Ill checkmark this in 5 mins when it lets me